# How to clear clob in PL SQL

Tags: plsql, clob

Created clob using

```
dbms.lob.createTemporary(v_clob,true)
```

and trying to free using

```
dbms.lob.freetemporary(v_clob)
```

It is not clearing the clob. 
Tried empty_clob() as well.

Comment: Assuming that you opened the clob, did you close it before freeing it?

Answer (score 3):

This should solve the problem:

```
v_clob := '';
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like below. Try this and check if it works for you.

```
DECLARE
   dummy  clob;
   dummy2 clob;
BEGIN
     dummy := empty_clob();
      IF dummy = empty_clob() THEN
         dummy2 := dummy;
      END IF;
END;
```

Edited: Please see an example. Hope this helps.

```
declare
       l_c clob := 'Hello World!';
       l_a number;
     begin

       l_a:=length(l_c);
       dbms_output.put_line( 'The original clob = *' || l_c || '*' );

      --Erase all the data in the clob. Emptying it.
       dbms_lob.erase( l_c, l_a );

       dbms_output.put_line( 'The clob modified now = *' || l_c || '*' );      
     end;
     /
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the correct way, but I had to initialize the CLOB in the beginning of each loop iteration. This has worked for me:

Dbms_Lob.CreateTemporary(v_clob, TRUE);